# Flutter_tts doesn't run on iOS

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, flutter, text-to-speech

I am trying to write an app that speaks text on flutter using [Flutter_tts](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/flutter_tts#-analysis-tab-) library, and it works fine for android, but when I try to run it on iOS device I get an error:

```
 === BUILD TARGET Runner OF PROJECT Runner WITH CONFIGURATION Debug ===
    ld: warning: Could not find auto-linked library 'swiftDispatch'
    ld: warning: Could not find auto-linked library 'swiftCoreMedia'
    ld: warning: Could not find auto-linked library 'swiftAVFoundation'
    ld: warning: Could not find auto-linked library 'swiftFoundation'
    ld: warning: Could not find auto-linked library 'swiftsimd'
    ld: warning: Could not find auto-linked library 'swiftObjectiveC'
    ld: warning: Could not find auto-linked library 'swiftCoreFoundation'
...
```

I previously switched my build system to legacy build system and specified my "Swift Language Version" to "Swift 4.2"

When I switch my build system to "New Build System" it gives me

```
Xcode's output:
↳
    error: Multiple commands produce '/Users/dimazhylko/FlutterProjects/flutter_tts_plugin_test/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/Runner.app/Frameworks/Flutter.framework':
    1) Target 'Runner' has copy command from '/Users/dimazhylko/FlutterProjects/flutter_tts_plugin_test/ios/Flutter/Flutter.framework' to '/Users/dimazhylko/FlutterProjects/flutter_tts_plugin_test/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/Runner.app/Frameworks/Flutter.framework'
    2) That command depends on command in Target 'Runner': script phase “[CP] Embed Pods Frameworks”
    warning: Not running swift-stdlib-tool: ALWAYS_EMBED_SWIFT_STANDARD_LIBRARIES is enabled, but the product type 'com.apple.product-type.library.static' is not a wrapper type. (in target 'Pods-Runner')
    warning: ignoring duplicated output file: '/Users/dimazhylko/FlutterProjects/flutter_tts_plugin_test/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/Runner.app/Frameworks/Flutter.framework' (in target 'Runner')
    note: Using new build systemnote: Planning buildnote: Constructing build description
```

Downgrading Swift version doesn't help too.

What else can I try to solve this problem?
Or maybe you can recommend another library?(I tried [Tts](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/tts#-example-tab-) already and it doesn't looks like good choice because it works only on flutter v"0.5.0"(Dart version 2.0.0<)

[I also get this warning when I open Xcode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wBtQ4.png)

Comment: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/20685

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known issue when creating your flutter project without the -i swift flag.  I outlined it here [similar issue](https://github.com/dlutton/flutter_tts/issues/4)

```
flutter create -i swift my_app
```

As a horrible work around, you can create a new flutter project with the -i swift flag and copy your files over from your current project.

Comment: Combining this two advices I got it built but now I have "timeout waiting for the application to start"

Answer (score 1):

Right-click on Runner, add a new Swift file.
XCode will ask you if you want to add Bridging Header. Accept and recompile.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/20685

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/20685#issuecomment-421511890

> There are two workarounds:
>
> - **Option 1: Use the legacy build system .** As noted by @gi097, open `ios/Runner.xcworkspace`, and change the build system to `Legacy Build
>     System`.
> - **Option 2: Use the new Xcode 10 build system.**
>
>   1. Open `ios/Runner.xcworkspace`
>   2. Select the `Runner` project in the project navigator sidebar.
>   3. In the main view, select the `Runner` target, then select the `Build Phases` tab.
>   4. Expand the `Embed Frameworks` phase and select `Flutter.framework` from the embedded frameworks list.
>   5. Click `-` to remove `Flutter.framework` from the list (be sure to *keep* `App.framework`).

and should be fixed already in `dev` and/or `master` channel.

Comment: I tried both and it doesn't help. In the last try I get: "clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
    note: Using new build systemnote: Planning buildnote: Constructing build description"

Comment: Sorry, no other ideas.